# Wix/MSI - Major Upgrade in silent mode

Tags: wix, windows-installer, silent-installer, major-upgrade

I have an installer with upgrade support from our previous version:

```
<Product Id="*" 
   Name="$(var.ProductName)" 
   Language="1033" 
   Version="$(var.InstallerVersion)" 
   Manufacturer="$(var.Manufacturer)" 
   UpgradeCode="$(var.UpgradeCode)">

<Upgrade Id="$(var.UpgradeCode)">
  <UpgradeVersion Minimum="$(var.InstallerVersion)" IncludeMinimum="no" OnlyDetect="yes" Property="NEWERVERSIONFOUND" />
  <UpgradeVersion Minimum="5.0.0" IncludeMinimum="yes" Maximum="$(var.InstallerVersion)" IncludeMaximum="yes" Property="OLDERVERSIONFOUND" MigrateFeatures="yes" />
  <UpgradeVersion Minimum="0.0.0" IncludeMinimum="yes" Maximum="5.0.0" IncludeMaximum="no" Property="OLDESTVERSIONFOUND" MigrateFeatures="yes" />
</Upgrade>

<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="SetReInstallProperty" After="FindRelatedProducts">OLDERVERSIONFOUND OR OLDESTVERSIONFOUND</Custom>
  <Custom Action="SetReInstallModeProperty" After="FindRelatedProducts">OLDERVERSIONFOUND OR OLDESTVERSIONFOUND</Custom>
  <RemoveExistingProducts After="InstallInitialize">OLDERVERSIONFOUND OR OLDESTVERSIONFOUND</RemoveExistingProducts>
```

When I run this installer over older version 4.2 in UI mode, upgrade works fine. But when I run it in silent mode with /q, it runs in maintenance mode and try to uninstall itself.

This is the parts of log:

```
MSI (s) (EC:00) [10:49:44:999]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding ACTION property. Its value is 'INSTALL'.
MSI (s) (EC:00) [10:49:44:999]: Doing action: INSTALL
Action start 10:49:44: INSTALL.
MSI (s) (EC:00) [10:49:44:999]: Running ExecuteSequence
MSI (s) (EC:00) [10:49:45:000]: Doing action: FindRelatedProducts
Action start 10:49:45: FindRelatedProducts.
MSI (s) (EC:00) [10:49:45:000]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding OLDESTVERSIONFOUND property. Its value is '{16DF8961-26DE-4A05-B759-102976C5EA22}'.
MSI (s) (EC:00) [10:49:45:000]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding MIGRATE property. Its value is '{16DF8961-26DE-4A05-B759-102976C5EA22}'.
MSI (s) (EC:00) [10:49:45:001]: Doing action: SetReInstallModeProperty
Action ended 10:49:45: FindRelatedProducts. Return value 1.
Action start 10:49:45: SetReInstallModeProperty.
MSI (s) (EC:00) [10:49:45:001]: Doing action: SetReInstallProperty
Action ended 10:49:45: SetReInstallModeProperty. Return value 1.
MSI (s) (EC:00) [10:49:45:001]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding REINSTALL property. Its value is 'all'.
```

...

```
MSI (s) (EC:00) [10:49:47:605]: Doing action: MigrateFeatureStates
Action ended 10:49:47: ReadNCPExtensions. Return value 1.
MSI (s) (EC:00) [10:49:47:605]: Migrating feature settings from product(s) '{16DF8961-26DE-4A05-B759-102976C5EA22}'
Action start 10:49:47: MigrateFeatureStates.
MSI (s) (EC:00) [10:49:47:606]: Doing action: InstallValidate
Action ended 10:49:47: MigrateFeatureStates. Return value 1.
Action start 10:49:47: InstallValidate.
MSI (s) (EC:00) [10:49:47:606]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Deleting MsiRestartManagerSessionKey property. Its current value is '0c59f7d17b575b409c4f5593caddd7f9'.
MSI (s) (EC:00) [10:49:47:606]: Feature: MainFeature; Installed: Absent;   Request: Null;   Action: Null
MSI (s) (EC:00) [10:49:47:606]: Component: C.Name1.dll; Installed: Absent;   Request: Null;   Action: Null
MSI (s) (EC:00) [10:49:47:606]: Component: C.Name2.dll; Installed: Absent;   Request: Null;   Action: Null
```

...

```
MSI (s) (EC:00) [10:49:47:621]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding REMOVE property. Its value is 'ALL'.
MSI (s) (EC:00) [10:49:47:622]: Doing action: SetARPINSTALLLOCATION
Action ended 10:49:47: InstallValidate. Return value 1.
MSI (s) (EC:00) [10:49:47:622]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding ARPINSTALLLOCATION property. Its value is 'C:\Program Files (x86)\SmartDrive Systems Inc\SmartDrive Data Forwarding Gateway\'.
Action start 10:49:47: SetARPINSTALLLOCATION.
MSI (s) (EC:00) [10:49:47:622]: Doing action: InstallInitialize
Action ended 10:49:47: SetARPINSTALLLOCATION. Return value 1.
MSI (s) (EC:00) [10:49:47:622]: Machine policy value 'AlwaysInstallElevated' is 0
MSI (s) (EC:00) [10:49:47:622]: User policy value 'AlwaysInstallElevated' is 0
MSI (s) (EC:00) [10:49:47:622]: BeginTransaction: Locking Server
MSI (s) (EC:00) [10:49:47:623]: SRSetRestorePoint skipped for this transaction.
MSI (s) (EC:00) [10:49:47:623]: Server not locked: locking for product {D097B768-E833-4511-A1F6-E51BD1A02258}
Action start 10:49:47: InstallInitialize.
MSI (s) (EC:00) [10:49:47:936]: Doing action: RemoveExistingProducts
Action ended 10:49:47: InstallInitialize. Return value 1.
MSI (s) (EC:00) [10:49:47:937]: Skipping RemoveExistingProducts action: current configuration is maintenance mode or an uninstall
Action start 10:49:47: RemoveExistingProducts.
MSI (s) (EC:00) [10:49:47:937]: Doing action: ProcessComponents
Action ended 10:49:47: RemoveExistingProducts. Return value 0.
Action start 10:49:47: ProcessComponents.
MSI (s) (EC:00) [10:49:47:938]: Doing action: UnpublishFeatures
Action ended 10:49:47: ProcessComponents. Return value 1.
Action start 10:49:47: UnpublishFeatures.
MSI (s) (EC:00) [10:49:47:938]: Doing action: StopServices
Action ended 10:49:47: UnpublishFeatures. Return value 1.
Action start 10:49:47: StopServices.
MSI (s) (EC:00) [10:49:47:939]: Doing action: DeleteServices
Action ended 10:49:47: StopServices. Return value 1.
Action start 10:49:47: DeleteServices.
```

The main feature names in both installers is different. When I change feature name in new version to the same as in 4.2, upgrade works in silent mode, but stop working in UI mode with similar log: after MigrateFeatureState all components is in state Installed: Absent;   Request: Null;   Action: Null and REMOVE set to ALL.
Any ideas why it behave so strange?

Comment: What is the command line used for silent mode installation? Also, i observed from the log that you are setting the value of  REINSTALL  to "all". Not sure if it makes a difference but can you set it to capital ALL  and try once? Also, can you confirm that both RemoveExistingProducts and MigrateFeature states are present in both the InstallUISequence and InstallExecuteSequence tables?

Comment: With REINSTALL="ALL" result the same.
MigrateFeatureStates present in both sequences. RemoveExistingProducts - in InstallExecuteSequence only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set main feature name the same as in old installer and removed my custom action SetReinstallProperty and upgrade works in both modes now.

Comment: In this case, what happens if you continue to use the REINSTALL property ? Just curious